# How do I host a shell for a serial terminal?

Tags: shell, gnu-screen, serial-console, minicom, agetty

I am building a dumb terminal with an arduino and I can now see the output of serial connections. How do I get a login/shell?
I have tried `screen /dev/ttyACM0` and that lets me type on the host computer and see the results on the terminal screen, but no shell. Using screen's `:exec /bin/sh` command starts a shell on that controlling xterm window but no longer outputs to the serial line. various attempts with `agetty -L /dev/ttyACM0 9600` just sit and hang for a minute then exits without ever having put anything on the screen. I have tried `cu -l /dev/ttyACM0 -s 9600` and again it hangs with no screen interaction. I have connected minicom to echo keys onto the arduino similar to screen but could not figure out how to get a shell. To be clear I am trying to access my main computer via the arduino based terminal, and I can not find a way to make my main computer offer a shell session to the arduino over a USB serial connection.

Comment: `setsid getty -8 -L /dev/ttyACM0 9600 dumb` as root *should* work, provided that `9600` is the right speed (I'm getting this from my command line history, I'm not able to test).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast answer. Unfortunately this didn't work either, No output shows up on the terminal, even trying vt100 instead of dumb and with and without the 8 bit part. Could it be that there is some signal to start the tty that the arduino is responsible for sending first? I am writing the arduino code myself so something like that could be missing if I didn't know about it but I can't find many resources on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`agetty` seems to be fairly quiet about problems. I tried:

```
$ strace -e open agetty -I 'hello\012' -L /dev/ttyS0 9600
```

and it opened `/dev//dev/ttyS0`, which failed of course. It then hung around a few seconds and stopped.

The man page does say it wants a relative filename, so I then tried:

```
$ strace -e open agetty -I 'hello\012' -L ttyS0 9600
```

and it opened the right device this time, but failed again:

```
open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Finally, this worked and wrote something on the tty:

```
$ sudo strace -e open agetty -I 'hello\012' -L ttyS0 9600
```

You should also add the `setsid` mentioned in the comments.
You can also use systemd (if you have it) to start the login with:

```
$ sudo systemctl start serial-getty@ttyACM0
```

This runs `agetty` with `--keep-baud 115200,38400,9600`.
If you `systemctl enable` the service, it might start automatically whenever device `ttyACM0` is created.

Comment: This got output on my screen, thank you so much. I appreciate you walking me through your process with strace as well, will be useful in the future.